# Hibernate Query Exception: Cannot create critieria on owning entity

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm unable to access the values in an Embedded Class.

```
Criteria cr = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().createCriteria(DuaVO.class,"Dua");

if (duaSearchVO.getContractNum()!=null && !duaSearchVO.getContractNum().isEmpty()) {
    cr.createCriteria("Dua.contractFundingDetails", "contractFundingDetails");
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("contractFundingDetails.contractNumber", duaSearchVO.getContractNum()));
    flag = true;
}
```

**Junit Test**

```
@Test
public void testsearchDua() {
    DuaSearchVO duaSearchVO = new DuaSearchVO();

    //ContractFundingDetailsVO - contractNumber
    duaSearchVO.setContractNum("HHS12132423");


    List<Object[]> result = duaSearchDaoImpl.searchDua(duaSearchVO);


    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
}
```

I get this exception.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: contractFundingDetails
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:230)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:112)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1568)
```

**Main Class (DuaVO)**

```
@Embedded
private ContractFundingDetailsVO contractFundingDetails;
```

**Embedded Class**

```
@Embeddable
    public class ContractFundingDetailsVO implements Serializable
   {
       @Column(name="CNTRCT_NUM")
       private String contractNumber;
      }
```

Comment: What is `Dua`? Does `cr.createCriteria("contractFundingDetails", "contractFundingDetails")` work?

Comment: I think The problem is on the eq restriction. Although can be in the mapping, maybe it's lazy?

Comment: @PredragMaric: I've updated the code and no, it gives me the same exception.

Comment: @AppSensei this thing works according to me  _Criteria cr = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().createCriteria(DuaVO.class);

if (duaSearchVO.getContractNum()!=null && !duaSearchVO.getContractNum().isEmpty()) {
    cr.createCriteria("contractFundingDetails", "contractFundingDetails");
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("contractFundingDetails.contractNumber", duaSearchVO.getContractNum()));
    flag = true;
}_
Also you can remove cr.createCriteria("contractFundingDetails", "contractFundingDetails") line

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I don't have to create a createCriteria() method since there are no joins.

```
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq
("Dua.contractFundingDetails.contractNumber", duaSearchVO.getContractNum()));

                flag = true;
            }
```

Comment: I face similar issue now with my embedded field. Do you know the solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733812/org-hibernate-queryexception-criteria-objects-cannot-be-created-directly-on-com/40735564?noredirect=1#comment68700384_40735564