# org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I face above issue when try to sort based on an embedded field;

eg: I try to sort with the property `tObservation.raw.waterLevel.metre`.
But getting following exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: tObservation.raw
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:251)
```

I create aliases like;

```
criteria.createAlias("tObservation", "0").createAlias("0.raw","1").createAlias("1.waterLevel","2").addOrder(Order.asc("2.meter"))
```

Why I get that exception?

The above code is working for two levels
eg: `tObservation.id`

p.s: If I try like;(without aliases)

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("tObservation.raw.waterLevel.metre"))
```

I get same exception.

My class structure

```
@Entity
class tank {

Observation tObservation;

}


@Entity
class Observation {

@Embedded
RawObservation raw;

}

@Embeddable
class RawObservation{

    @Embedded
Length waterLevel;
}

@Embeddable
class Length{
BigDecimal metre

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this :

```
Criteria cObserv = criteria.createCriteria("tObservation");
cObserv.createAlias("raw", "r");
cObserv.createAlias("r.waterLevel", "rw");

cObserv.createAlias("rw.metre", "rwm");
or
cObserv.setFetchMode("rw.metre", FetchMode.JOIN);

cObserv.addOrder(Order.asc("rw.metre"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
Criteria cObservation = criteria.createCriteria("tObservation");
Criteria cRaw = cObservation.createCriteria("raw");
Criteria cWaterLevel = cRaw.createCriteria("waterLevel");
cWaterLevel.addOrder(Order.asc("meter"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. So, creating aliases is wrong in this case?

Comment: I am not sure. I noticed one thing though. Your entity Length has metre field but order uses meter. It also could be the reason

Comment: I get same exception //Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property: tObservation.raw
 at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPathInfo(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:251)
 at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.createCriteriaEntityNameMap(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:212)
 at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.<init>(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:94)
//

Comment: This works for associations, but not for embedded attributes